# getting undefined selected value from dropdown in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I am new to learn react native. I want to get selected value from dropdown in react-native.

my constructor

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = ({       
        PickerSelectedVal : ''
      })
}
```

in render

```
render(){
      <Dropdown                 
                label="Select"
                options={["Op1","Op2"]}                     
                selectedValue={this.state.PickerSelectedVal}
                onSelect={(obj)=>this.changedemo({obj})}
      />
}
```

in function

```
 changedemo= (ob)=>{
      this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob});
      alert("Selected country is : " +ob.PickerSelectedVal);
      console.log(this.state.PickerSelectedVal);
      if (this.state.PickerSelectedVal === 1) {
          alert("Selected value is : " +ob.PickerSelectedVal);
      } 
      if(this.state.PickerSelectedVal === 0) {
alert("Selected value is : " +ob.PickerSelectedVal);
      }

  }
```

I have tried many times. I want to get selected value from dropdown alert is also showing but it prints.
Selected value is:undefined.

Answer (score 1):

setState is a async process so when you are printing it by that time the state is not yet set. 
Add This

```
this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob},()=>{console.log(this.state.PickerSelectedVal)});
```

Comment: thank you! I can show in console. but in alert not showing value. it shows undefined.

Answer (score 0):

your changedemo function must be like following;

```
  changedemo= (ob)=>{
      this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob.value});
      alert("Selected country is : " +ob.value);
      console.log(ob.value);
      // rest of the code
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply!    alert("Selected country is : " +this.state.PickerSelectedVal);   but it shows only Selected Country is :   blank value not print any value.

Comment: on first line of changedemo function start add following line 
alert(ob); and comment here output.

Comment: which package you are using for dropdown?

Comment: I have added alert(ob);  it show output : [object Object]. I can show object in log also output: { obj: { index: '0', value: 'Op1' } }

Comment: ok so now try this
alert("Selected country is : " +ob.value);

Comment: with try alert(ob.value);    Alert undefined output.

Comment: are you sure, you are using `ob` everywhere instead of `obj`?

Comment: I can get output object in console. using this line this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob},()=>{console.log(this.state.PickerSelectedVal)});  but I want to show on alert also.

Comment: you need to pass ob.value to PickerSelectedVal, not the whole object.
`this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob.value});`
`alert(this.state.PickerSelectedVal)`

Comment: I have tried this  this.setState({PickerSelectedVal : ob.value}); alert(this.state.PickerSelectedVal);    but alert shows blank not displaying anything.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. Comment your function for some time and add my code and check.

Comment: I have tried your code. it display only Selected country is : not display selected value.

Comment: if I change from dropdown again. it shows Selected country is : undefined value.

Comment: I have tried your updated code it shows Alert Selected country is : undefined value.

Comment: if on a console it is showing you `obj` ({ obj: { index: '0', value: 'Op1' } }) then use `console.log(obj.value); alert(obj.value)` and try

Comment: getting this output in log : { obj: { index: '0', value: 'Op1' } } but in console.log(ob.value); first time it shows blank in console. after change again value in dropdown it shows undefined.

Comment: see in the log when you printed your value which shows you object named `obj` which means wherever you are using ob.value you need to use **`obj.value`**

Comment: I have changed it with ob to obj. still not working. showing undefined.